# Downgrade to official LG GT540 2.1updated

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, 2.1-eclair, cyanogenmod, lg-optimus-one, downgrade

I've installed Android 2.3 (Cyanogen Mod) to my LG GT540 phone, but it's too unstable. I would like to downgrade back to 2.1update (it's the OS I have when I buy the phone), or any official newer version. Where can I get official LG version, and how to install it? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Did you try the answer on this other question tagged "downgrade"? http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11981/nexus-one-manual-update-and-back-to-previous-version-to-2-1-android

Comment: Where can I find original rom?